# How do I test if a std::thread is moved from?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move-semantics

I have a movable noncopyable class with a std::thread member.

When the class destructor runs I need to do some cleanup work and join the thread.
If the class is moved from I need the destructor to skip the cleanup and thread joining.
I could just accomplish this by storing a bool moved from but that seems a bit wasteful.

If the std::thread member is moved from then I know this class instance is moved from. Is it possible to check if the std::thread member is moved from?

```
class Widget
{
    Widget()
    {
        // initialize
    }

    Widget( Widget&& rhs )
    {
        t = std::move(rhs.t);
    }

    ~Widget()
    {
        if ( t_is_not_moved_from() )
        {
            // do cleanup
            t.join();
        }
    }

    inline friend void swap( Widget& lhs, Widget& rhs )
    {
        lhs.t.swap( rhs.t );
    }

private:
    std::thread t;

    // noncopyable
    Widget( const Widget& );
    const Widget& operator=( const Widget& );
};
```

Comment: You don't have to write move constructor and destructor, just for the std::thread. The default generated ones will do exactly what you wish to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike most standard library objects, `std::thread`'s move constructor does clearly dictate the state of a moved-from `thread`. It is equvialent to an empty thread: `thread.joinable` will be `false`.

Comment: @MichaelMarcin:  Yes, it is safe to call `joinable()` on a moved-from thread.  This member function has no preconditions, and can thus be called no matter what unspecified state a `thread` is in.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: The state of a moved-from thread is not unspecified. The spec is clear that it will be empty: the thread's `id` will be in the "default constructed state".